# Why use Message Forwarding

Tags: objective-c

Why would you use Message Forwarding in Objective-c. Also when using it, you need to call the Surragate method with performSelector? I am thinking you have a lot of knowledge when you are coding this, why would you need Message Forwarding. I am reading that this is Obj-c multiple inheritance - but I don't see it like this, it is just another object attached to an object.

Hope you know and have a pratical example

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my discussion at the end of this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uitabbar

Here I have interposed my own object as the data source for one of Apple's table views. I don't know how the table view works (it's Apple's) and I don't know what their data source does (it's Apple's). So I substitute my own data source but I keep Apple's, and any messages that I don't handle that arrive at my data source are passed on to Apple's. Thus in a sense I have made my data source "inherit" from Apple's.

```
@implementation MyDataSource

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([self.originalDataSource respondsToSelector: aSelector])
        return self.originalDataSource;
    return [super forwardingTargetForSelector:aSelector];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sec {
    // this is just to quiet the compiler
    return [self.originalDataSource tableView:tv numberOfRowsInSection:sec];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)ip {
    // this is why we are here: my tweaks
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.originalDataSource tableView:tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans-Bold" size:14];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks; So this could have been done with inheritance and overriding the methods of interest?

Comment: Not at all. There's no class to inherit from. That's why I did it this way.

Comment: Ahh, so in essence "Message Forwarding" can be justified in situations with Protocols?

Comment: Not at all. - Message forwarding isn't a crime; it doesn't need to be "justified". It is a technique like any other, a tool in your toolbox. It's an architecture for dealing with the arrival of messages to which the receiving object itself does not respond.

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it. Doing it this way you don't need to implement alle the methods in the protocol, you simply just hook into the one you need and forward the rest - right?

Comment: Forget the protocol, it's a red herring. Think about the situation. I'm interposing myself in front of one of Apple's totally private objects. I have _no idea_ what the object I'm replacing does, what messages it may receive. I only know _one_ message it may receive, the one I want to replace. But I need things to keep working correctly. So I implement the one message I know about, and pass all the others on to the original object by message forwarding so that everything keeps working.

Comment: But that is hardly the only situation where message forwarding is useful. Imagine that I have wrapped another object - an NSArray, say. (You can't subclass NSArray so it is safer to wrap it.) So I have one or two custom messages that I handle, and everything else is just passed right along to the NSArray.